# What is the user 'mobile' for on iPad?

Tags: ssh, ios, darwin

I just `ssh`ed to a jailbroken iPad(Pro 3, iOS 14.2), and found other than `root` and `daemon`, there's an existing user `mobile`, which seems to come with the system. I was wondering

1. what the user is for?
2. if I do not change the password, can others ssh to my device with this account?
3. if I do change the password, can it mess with the normal system operation?

Answer (score 1):

`mobile` is the default Non-Privileged user for the device. This user is for using the terminal when you do not need escalated privileges for everything (*i.e.* `root`). Since it is an existing user, I would recommend changing it and all other default passwords you haven't changed yet as that is a security risk. Your system will function all the same, just make sure you remember the password if you ever need to get back in!

I would also like to note that is it better practice to login to the non-privileged user account and [escalate to root as needed.](https://www.howtogeek.com/124950/htg-explains-why-you-shouldnt-log-into-your-linux-system-as-root/)